# Network printers and the PrintServer.GetPrintQueues method

Tags: vb.net, printing, system.printing, printqueue

I have a feeling that the [PrintServer.GetPrintQueues method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printserver.getprintqueues.aspx) **does not** return the network printers.

If this one is true, what other choices do i have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot of Googling the GetPrintQueues method **do return** the network printers too with aid of EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes()

`Private enumerationFlags As EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes() = {EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections}`

More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.enumeratedprintqueuetypes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Management Instrumentation.

See [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=148&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) for an example of now to get the network printers using WMI.